# Meaning of the solutions of a system of equations

Tags: calculus, functions

I'm new at this forum and I'm not expert in mathematics, but I'll try my best to use a propper notation to explain my doubt. Imagine a system of equations like the following one:

$$f_1(x,y,\cdots n) = 0$$

$$f_2(x,y,\cdots n) = 0$$

$$\vdots$$

$$f_n(x,y,\cdots n) = 0$$

If I'm not misstaken, finding the solutions of the aforementioned system means that at least one of the $f_i(x,y,\cdots n)$ is zero. I'm wondering if by resolving the system of equation you'll find each solution that nullifies each $f_i(x,y,\cdots n)$ or, on the contrary, you'll only find the solutions that are zeros of the system, which leads to the possibility that each $f_i(x,y,\cdots n)$ has more solutions than the ones found by resolving the system.

For me at least, It sounds kind of a tricky question to ask, so if you need any acclaration about my doubt, just let me know and I'll be glad to clarify it.

Comment: For each indiviual equation $f_i(\vec{x}) = 0$ there is an infinite number of solutions if $\vec{x}$ has more than one dimension. For the whole system however there may be none, finitely or infinitely many solutions for $\vec{x}$. Obviously a solution of the system also fulfills each equation individually.

Comment: @Christian this is only true if the function is linear. $\sum_{k=1}^nx_k^2$=0 has only one solution.

Comment: @MathR not if $x \in \mathbb{C}$

Comment: @MathR $\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_{k}^{2}$ is not linear, but I see what you meant.

Comment: Thank you very much all of you! I see, and that what I'm affraid of, that each individual equation has infinite number of solutions. Anyway, that was really helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, you can have a unique solution, an infinite number of solutions, or no solutions.
Consider a system of linear equations with $n$ unknown variables $(x_1, x_2, ... x_n)$
If you have less equations - $f_{i<n}(x_1,...,x_n)$  than unknown variables, it means you have an infinite number of solutions. Example $x_1+x_2+x_3=0$
Therefore you have an infinite ways to express $(x_i)_{1\leq i \leq 3}$ using the other variables $((x_k, x_j)_{1 \leq k\neq j \leq 3})$. $-x_1-x_2 = x_3$
This is something usual in Linear Algebra when you're trying to find the rang of a Matrix, find generating families of linear subspaces, etc.
If you have more equations - $f_{i > n}(x_1, ... , x_n)$ than variables, it means either one or more equation(s) is/are a combination of other equations, therefore doesn't bring anything new to the table, either is incompatible with your other equations in your system. Consider
(a) $x_1+x_2=2$
(b) $x_1-x_2=0$
(c) $x_1+x_2=3$
(d) $2x_1+2x_2 = 4$
In this case (c) is incompatible with your other 2 equations (a) and (d), i.e  (a) and (c) can't have a solution that is true for both equations.
(d) is (a) multiplied by the scalar $2$.
So if you have (a) and (c) in a system, the system has $0$ solutions. If you have (a) and (d) in your system, the system has an infinite number of solutions. If you have (a) and (b) your system has a unique solution $x_1=x_2=1$
You can view a system of equations as a matrix times a vector = some other vector. If you want to know whether a system has a unique solution or is inconsistent/incompatible you can look up *Cramer's rule* for solving linear systems of equations. Hopefully this answers your questions.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! That was a real complete one, but I was looking an answer more likely to the one @Christian gave to me. I was wondering about the relation between the solutions of the system of equations and the solutions of each equation by itself. Anyway, you make me realise that I have to take into account more things to solve my problem such as the use of Cramer's rule.

Comment: You're welcome!